# Why is this C++ Regex code bad?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

When I compile my program it doesn't compile, it just gives me a lot (and I mean really a lot) of text and errors. What is wrong with this?

```
const boost::regex expr("[A-Za-z_]+ +'='+ [0-9]+");
```

Sample errors:

`C:\Users\Hunix\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKDhlNb.o:kat.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail27cpp_regex_traits_char_layerIcEC2ERKNS0_21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEE[boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_trait_char_layer<char>::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer(boost::re_d etail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char> const&)]+0x55): undefined reference to boost ::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'`

`C:\Users\Hunix\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKDhlNb.o:kat.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail11raw_storage6extendEj[boost::re_detail::raw_storage::extend(unsigned int)]+0x40) : undefined reference to boost::re_detail::raw_storage::`

Comment: I did what you said @Niall, but it's not better. :( It's only good if I leave the expr() without parameters.

Comment: Try using https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: @hunix: Please edit your question to add the error messages.

Comment: It appears you have a link error, not a compile error. You have to add the Boost regex library to your libraries list.

Comment: @Niall AFAIK you don't need to escape single quote inside double quotes.

Comment: @Arkadiy. This appears to be correct...

Comment: Your regex works ok using `boost::regex`, its a little strange so the problem lies with linking the libraries. I tested with [RegexFormat](http://www.regexformat.com), which contains embedded boost regex engine to test regex with. That portion of the program is free, to format you need a key.

Comment: @sln so how can I fix it?